# String Manipulation using regex and rules

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm new to regex but it looks as though this will work for what I need, but I just can't get my head around it.

I have a string "MAMMOTH 9MM" as an example.

All should stay upper case except the specified chars of "MM" after any digit.

Should be simple?

Comment: a) try something b) we need more example of expected input and output

Comment: You have not included a regex, but say *it looks as though this will work*. Also, you've not explained specifically what you want to do, and *Should be simple?* is a meaningless question (unless you'll accept *Yes, it should* as an answer). Please read [ask] and then come back and [edit] your question to a) clearly explain the problem you're trying to solve, b) show what you've done to try and solve it yourself and explain why it's not working, and c) ask a **specific question** that we can answer.

Comment: Also what does this have to do with c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for regular expression patterns and apply a lambda function to modify the matches:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\b[0-9]+)MM\b", m => m.ToLower())
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked a treat